# How do I write an if statement to determine whether to display an attribute in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

This throws an error. Unexpected token for eachOption:

```
<input {eachOption===selectedValue?'checked="checked"':''} type="checkbox" name="checkme"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace with `checked={eachOption === selectedValue}`.

That should do the trick.

However, make sure you also have the `onChange` handler attached to the checkbox (as any other input that you would like to use in React), otherwise it might not behave as you'd expect.

You should set values for attributes using JSX.

By setting the value of `checked` to false, it will mean that the checkbox will not be checked. If the condition (`eachOption === selectedValue`) holds then the checkbox will be checked for you.

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dimacazoru/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: It's not going to work - see below in my response answer:

Comment: It will work, however you need to also add an `onChange` handler, because all React created inputs expect one.

Comment: @SteveTomlin please look at this example https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html it is from facebook and uses `checked={boolean}` in their checkbox. JSX != HTML

Comment: @SteveTomlin Have you ever worked with JSX?  Here's an example of this answer working perfectly: https://jsbin.com/cefogejono/edit?js,output

Comment: ok but I don't want to add an onChange even handler. Why is that important?

Comment: If you don't want to toggle the checkbox by using the checkbox, then that's fine. If that's the case, you can refer to the example @MichaelParker posted in his JSBin. You can alter the value externally by other means / sources.

Comment: If you want to specify the `checked` attribute of a checkbox, you are creating a [Controlled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).  This means that the value of that DOM node will always be consistent with some variable, and users will not actually be able to modify it themselves without specifying an `onChange` handler that implements this behavior.