# How to add disabled attribute via prop to a button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am creating a custom button component in react. I want to pass a prop to that button, based on the value of which button gets enabled or disabled.

My problem is 
- The mere presence of the disabled property disables the element, so I cannot set its value as "false". Even the following code is disabling the element

```
<input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Submit" disabled="" />
```

I need to either remove the attribute completely or set its property via javascript.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
```

My custom button component is -

```
import React from 'react';

const CustomButton = ({ whenClicked, classNames, buttonText, isDisabled }) =>
    (
        <button
            onClick   = {whenClicked}
            className = {`btn ${classNames}`}
            type      = "button"
            disabled  = {isDisabled}
        >
           {buttonText}
        </button>
    );

export default CustomButton;
```

`isDisabled` is a boolean value.

One more thing, I lost the default submit behavior of button while using custom button. Now I always need to pass a click handler. Is there any way to achieve the same behavior again?

Comment: Enable the element, set the property, disable it again.

Comment: `disabled={false}` works.. are you passing a string instead of the actual value `false` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you currently have should work perfectly fine. Be careful that when you use `CustomButton` you don't send in the value for `disabled` as a `string`. That will make it disabled regardless of what you pass in. Instead, you need to pass in a boolean, that's in JSX syntax.

Here's a sample usage where you would put it inside of a render function of a component that uses the button:

```
...
render() {
    <div>
        ...
        <CustomButton
            whenClicked={() => console.log('I just got clicked')}
            buttonText="Some Button"
            isDisabled={false}
        />
        ...
    </div>
   }
...
```

Basically, instead of false you could pass in something else. You could pass in a boolean value that's stored on the props of the container that holds the `CustomButton`.

You could say `isDisabled={this.props.disableInnerButton}` and it would work as you would expect. Changing the value of the boolean will disable or enable the button.

Below you can find a relevant answer I gave recently on a very similar topic:

[Statement to add or not an attribute in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059192/how-do-i-write-an-if-statement-to-determine-whether-to-display-an-attribute-in-j)

Comment: You are right I was using string instead of boolean value.

Comment: One more thing I lost default submit behavior of button while using custom button. Now I always need to pass click handler. is there any way to achieve the same behavior again?

Comment: Just make sure the `type` of the button is `submit`. As long as it is inside the form, it should work out of the box.

Comment: but buttons default behavior is submit right? Still I need to set type `submit` explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

At first it looks quite complicated to handle but, if we look at the problem I think we can achive it using css only by adding a class(selector) to the element

```
.disabled { pointer-events: none;}
```

or conditionally styling:

```
<button style={{pointerEvents: notValid ? "none" : "initial"}}> Submit </button>
```